# GridView in ASP.NET Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have below mark-up code in my ASPX page.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdVw" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Below C# code in my ASPX.CS page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ds.Tables.Add(getDT());
    }

    rep.DataSource = ds.Tables;
    rep.DataBind();
}    

private DataTable getDT()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("One");
    dt.Columns.Add("Two");
    dt.Columns.Add("Three");

    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["One"] = "Value1";
    row["Two"] = "Value2";
    row["Three"] = "Value3";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    return dt;
}
```

My intention is to have multiple gridviews depends on the number of tables of my dataset. After I run this code, I see nothing on the page. I don't know what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: You can try `grdVw` instead of  `rep` `grdVw.DataSource = ds.Tables;`

Comment: If I try `grdVw.DataSource = ds.Tables` I am getting columns like: CaseSensitive IsInitialized, RemotingFormat, DisplayExpression, HasErrors, MinimumCapacity, TableName, Namespace, Prefix, DesignMode

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnItemDataBound` event of the Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rep_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdVw" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in code begind find the nested GridView and bind the correct DataSet to it.

```
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = e.Item.FindControl("grdVw") as GridView;
    gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[e.Item.ItemIndex];
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can suggest you:

```
    //after these lines
    rep.DataSource = ds.Tables;
    rep.DataBind();

    //add below lines:
    int count = 1;
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rep.Items)
    {
        var grd = item.FindControl("grdVw") as GridView;
        grd.DataSource = ds.Tables[count - 1];
        grd.DataBind();
        count++;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `count = 0; grd.DataSource = ds.Tables[count];`